# How to delete a list and create a new list in firebase android?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Im having a database as below,

[image: firebase database]

Here, I want to dynamically delete the existing list "20211127",
and add a new list with a different name in place of deleted one.

I have been going over this issue for 6 days now, without a solution. Could you please help me with this?

Comment: Firebase does not support the option to delete a list by index or id. What you should do, is make the changes to the document (a class that holds the data) in your code, and then update it, by the `update` function of Firebase

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To remove the existing node and add a new node in one operation would be something like this:

```
String listToDelete = "20211127";
String listToAdd = "20220629";
Map dataToAdd = ...; //  You have to provide this

Map updates = new HashMap<String, Object>();
updates.put("cafeTrans/"+listToDelete, null);
updates.put("cafeTrans/"listToAdd, dataToAdd);
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().updateChildren(updates);
```

Comment: I appreciate your input, Frank. It solved my issue on point. Thank you